# How to set the left menu on the product page?

Tags: magento-1.9, template, layered-navigation, product-view

I have a link `left.phtml` in `catalog.hml`. But I want to show it on the product page too.

[image]

```
    Category layered navigation layout
-->

    <catalog_category_layered translate="label">
        <label>Catalog Category (Anchor)</label>
        <reference name="left_first">
            <block type="catalog/navigation" name="catalog.leftnav.browse" after="currency" template="catalog/navigation/left.phtml">
                <block type="core/text_list" name="catalog.leftnav.state.renderers" as="state_renderers" />
            </block>
            <block type="catalog/layer_view" name="catalog.leftnav" after="currency" template="catalog/layer/view.phtml">
                <block type="core/text_list" name="catalog.leftnav.state.renderers" as="state_renderers" />
                <action method="unsetChild"><alias>category_filter</alias></action>
            </block>
        </reference>
```

Comment: @sergrey Eremin what is this file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for the rwd theme used reference name`left_first` for other use `left`

```
<catalog_product_view translate="label">
<reference name="left_first">
    <block type="catalog/navigation" name="catalog.leftnav.browse" after="currency" template="catalog/navigation/left.phtml"/>
</reference>                
</catalog_product_view>
```

Comment: i want to do the same task like this only in one specific category product detail page.Can you pls explain in which file i want to do the changes.

Comment: go to admin panel   `edit cateogry >   custom design  > custom Layout Update`  add this `<reference name="left_first">
    <block type="catalog/navigation" name="catalog.leftnav.browse" after="currency" template="catalog/navigation/left.phtml"/>
</reference> `

Comment: Thank you @Qaisar.shall i post a question on this or my request is same as this question

Comment: @mujas separate question is better because it will help community too.

Comment: ill ask a question.

Comment: please check this question http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/99003/how-to-add-filter-option-in-product-details-page