# How to add filter option in product details page?

Tags: magento-1.7, products, layered-navigation, filter, filtered-nav

I have a category called `perfume` in my website.
I manage to show the **default filter** in the left side of this category.
I want to add the same default filter in the product detail page **only for** the **perfume category products**.

**List Page**
[image]

**Details Page**
[image]

I updated the `edit cateogry > custom design > custom Layout Update` with below lines.

```
<reference name="product_list">
<action method="setTemplate"><template>catalog/product/perfume.phtml</template></action>
</reference>
<reference name="product.info">
<action method="setTemplate"><template>catalog/product/perfume-view.phtml</template></action>
</reference>
<remove name="left.newsletter" />
```

**How can i add this filter in the perfume category product details page?**

Comment: you want to show layered navigation on product view page?

Comment: Yes @QaisarSatti.I want to show the same left side shopping option like list page

Comment: That are not possible because layered navigation need collection.

Comment: @QaisarSatti.hope you understood my requirement.so there is no any methods to perform this?

Comment: Can you explain what you want to filter by when only viewing one product? Unfortunately what you are trying to do makes no sense.

Comment: @mujas i understand that you can use that method http://www.manadev.com/blog/layered-navigation-on-home-or-any-other-cms-page

Comment: @ProxiBlue i update the layout for my own design.I need to add the filters in product details page too.

Comment: @QaisarSatti i mange to do this.check my answer.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to do the task by adding some code in to `Custom Layout Update` of the product.

```
<reference name="left">
<block type="catalog/layer_view" name="catalog.leftnav" before="-" template="catalog/layer/view.phtml"/>
</reference>
```

Now i can view the layered navigation on my specific product page.
for the full functionality(Search n filter) of the layered navigation in the product detail page i edit the `filter.phtml -`**`app\design\frontend\base\default\template\catalog\layer\`**) - url for the label link.

```
<ol>
<?php $baseUrl = Mage::getBaseUrl(); ?>
<?php foreach ($this->getItems() as $_item): ?>
<li>
    <?php if ($_item->getCount() > 0): ?>
    <?php 
        $urls =  explode("?",$this->urlEscape($_item->getUrl())); 

        $new_url = $baseUrl."perfume.html?".$urls[1];
    ?>
    <?php /*?><a href="<?php echo $this->urlEscape($_item->getUrl()) ?>"><?php echo $_item->getLabel() ?></a><?php */?>

    <a href="<?php echo $new_url ?>"><?php echo $_item->getLabel() ?></a>
    <?php else: echo $_item->getLabel() ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
    <?php if ($this->shouldDisplayProductCount()): ?>
    (<?php echo $_item->getCount() ?>)
    <?php endif; ?>
</li>
<?php endforeach ?>
</ol>
```

**Please Kindly Notice that is based on my requirement i did it.I want the layered navigation on only one specific category's(Perfume) product detail page.**

I hope this will help to some one in future.

Comment: did you add the collection or just simply adding by that?

Comment: I did not do anything to my perfume-view.phtml. I update the Custom Layout Update as in the answer.for the search function completion i did the little change on filter.phtml(app\design\frontend\base\default\template\catalog\layer\)

Comment: you remove the product  check from there?

Comment: what do you mean by product Check?

Comment: there were a check if product count greater then zero..

Comment: did you mean this one if(!$_productCollection->count())

Comment: yes this is i am talking and also these changes effect the search and category too

Comment: I did not remove this

Comment: add you change too in answer so it make it clear..

Comment: add  what line you edit of filter.phtml and whate change you made